# Google App Engine フレキシブル環境でポートの制御をしたい

Tags: node.js, google-cloud, google-app-engine

今、GAEのフレキシブル環境を使ってNode.jsアプリケーションを開発しています。

その中で使っていないポートを塞ぐことが可能なのか、ということが気になり質問しました。
調べても設定画面や方法について見つけることができませんでした。

**どこかの設定画面やコマンドでポートの制御は可能なのでしょうか？**
どなたか教えてください。

※Dockerイメージのデプロイなどは行っていません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> どこかの設定画面やコマンドでポートの制御は可能なのでしょうか？

いいえ、ポートの制御はできません。

Appe Engine フレキシブル環境におけるNode.jsのドキュメントによると、GAE側が提供するPORT環境変数にアプリケーションがバインドされるものの、他のポートについては言及されておらず、ユーザー側からの制御は不可能なようです。

> ランタイムは npm start を使用してアプリケーションを起動します。
>   （中略）
>   起動スクリプトはウェブサーバーを起動し、それが PORT 環境変数で指定されたポート（一般的には 8080）で HTTP リクエストに応答します。
>   [Node.js ランタイム  |  Node.js ドキュメントに対応した App Engine フレキシブル環境  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime?hl=ja)

ただし、Dockerを利用したカスタムランタイム環境ではポートの制御が可能です。
必要に応じてこちらも参照してみてください。
[フレキシブル環境用の Google App Engine カスタム ランタイムのドキュメント  |  App Engine フレキシブル環境用カスタム ランタイム  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/?hl=ja)

Comment: 予想はしていたのですがやはりユーザーでの設定は難しいのですね。
回答ありがとうございます。